# How to rollback a migration from a Laravel 4 package?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4 package that contains a migration script with both `up` and `down` methods implemented. I can run the migrations using `artisan`:

```
php artisan migrate --bench="vendor/package"
```

But how can I rollback that migration for my package?

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --bench="vendor/package"
```

That last results in:

> [RuntimeException]
>     The "--bench" option does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do that is using the general artisan command:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Which will *rollback* all your migrations.